# Azure Media Player show controls on hover or mouseover

Tags: azure-media-services

My jQuery solution works, but it's a bit hacky.  The documentation is lacking in information and examples.

Docs here:  https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.player.controls

My solution:

```
$(".azuremediaplayer").hover(function () {
    $(".vjs-control-bar").css({
        "visibility": "visible",
        "opacity": "1"
    })
}, function () {
    $(".vjs-control-bar").css({
        "visibility": "hidden",
         "opacity": "0"
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you could leverage the following approaches:

[amp.player.options.controls](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.player.options.controls)

```
var myOptions = {
"nativeControlsForTouch": true,
controls: true, //set to true
autoplay: true,
width: "640",
height: "400",
}
myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
myPlayer.src([
  {"src":"https://sec.ch9.ms/ch9/cf2b/d75f604a-e59f-46f2-81d3-4ec1473ecf2b/AzureFridayGetStartedWithAzureFor_mid.mp4"}
]);
```

[amp.player.controls](https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.player.controls)

```
myPlayer = amp("azuremediaplayer", myOptions);
myPlayer.controls(true);
```

Moreover, for a simpler way, you could visit [here](http://ampdemo.azureedge.net/azuremediaplayer.html) to customize your settings and get the player code.